# Iterating through hierarchy of packages in Enterprise Architect using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, add-in, enterprise-architect

I have to iterate and collect upto 5 levels of packages from Enterprise Architect. There are various such level inside the main root package. Till now i have been using recursive way like below:

```
public void GetAllPackages(EA.Package dumpPackage)
{
    foreach (EA.Package packages in dumpPackage.Packages)
    {
        //Save that package in object
        GetAllPackages(packages);
    }
}
```

But now since the data is more this loop is taking a lot of time nearly 1 minute to complete. Is there any faster way to iterate and collect all these packages.

Comment: can you please share a bit in context of how this recursive call is used?

Comment: Actually i need to collect all packages inside the dumpPackage. There is a total of 5 level of packages inside this root package and i need to collect them and show them in a tree view in add-in. So i am using this recursive call to go inside each and every package in the levels

Comment: is the repository on a local file or is it in on a db server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is to get all packages in s single query with

```
Repository.SQLQuery("SELECT package_id, parent_id FROM t_package")
```

Now place them in a hash so you have a tree with all children of a package referenced. That is, each entry receives a list of child packages so you can easily traverse this tree for any package you need.

A recursive SQL is not possible (at least in the SQL dialects I know). But the above will for sure be much faster since the bottleneck are the repetitive SQLs for single packages EA will issue during a recursive traverse.

**Alternative 1**
This solution requires that you create a query with the SQL query builder:

```
SELECT pkg.package_id FROM t_object o, t_package pkg
WHERE
  pkg.Package_id in (#Branch#)
  AND o.Package_ID = pkg.package_id
  AND o.Object_Type = 'Package'
```

Now you need to focus on the package you want to recurse and then run the search with

```
Respository.GetElementsByQuery (<QueryName>, "")
```

where `<QueryName>` is the name of your query.

I have no idea how this will improve performance. The `#Branch#` macro will be evaluated internally in EA and I don't know how this is done. Hopefully it is faster than a script recursion. Just try the above query manually and see if it's fast enough.

**Alternative 2**
You could use a SQL with a fixed number of `JOIN`s to dive into a number of levels like in

```
t_object INNER JOIN t_package AS ObjectParent ON  t_object.package_id = ObjectParent.package_id)
LEFT JOIN t_package AS PackageParent1 ON (ObjectParent.Parent_ID = PackageParent1.package_id))
LEFT JOIN t_package AS PackageParent2 ON (PackageParent1.Parent_ID = PackageParent2.package_id))
```

But that's rather RDBMS-dependent and you have to try out yourself.

Comment: It works but i think i did not make the requirement clear. I need to iterate through a particular package and its content only but this one iterates through the entire model and hence lots of data is coming so considerably the time take is nearly equal. Is there a way i can set the value of t_package. I tried few things but i am not able to achieve the desired output.

Comment: I have added an alternative solution.

Comment: And another variant as well.